# Saving a web page to a file in Java

Tags: java, http, sockets

I am trying to read html site using below code,System hanging any hints please:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;   
import java.io.FileWriter;   
import java.net.Socket;  
import javax.net.SocketFactory;  
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class writingFile {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {

        SocketFactory factory=SocketFactory.getDefault();
        Socket socket=new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("java.sun.com"), 80);
        BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://test.html"));
        int data;

        while((data=socket.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
            out.write((char)data);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Regards,
Raj

Comment: What exception are you getting? Might be more helpful if you told us.

Comment: What exception is it throwing? and where?

Comment: I bet you do not have the IP of java.sun.com....

Comment: What is the exception? You need to provide as much information as possible. You are getting an exception, is a very broad statement.

Comment: I am not able to write the content into html file

Comment: Can you add the actual content of the exception message?

Comment: Guys,If you are able to figure it out the problem,please provide comment instead of down voting.If there is no answer for it doesn't mean down voting

Comment: I am not getting any exception here,it hangs..

Comment: you're getting downvoted because you are asking a question and not providing any context.

Comment: Looks it is having problem in while loop.

Comment: Your question will most likely get closed if you don't provide the exception message

Comment: @Raju, you should edit your question and describe exactly what the current behavior is.  Also, try adding a few Sysout.println statements to see exactly where it is hanging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). You can't just open a socket and start reading something. You have to be polite to the server and send a request first:

```
socket.getOutputStream().write("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n".getBytes());
socket.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Then read a HTTP response, **parse it**, and get your html page back.

**EDIT** I wrote what to do with sockets only because it was the immediate problem of the OP. Using URLConnection is the correct way, as answered by @Mike Deck.

Comment: using your hint i able to solve it,when i give sub context like bbc.co.uk/news/,it is throwing UnknownHostException

Comment: This is what i did,SocketFactory socketFactory=SocketFactory.getDefault(); Socket socket=socketFactory.createSocket(InetAddress.getByName("bbc.co.uk/news"),80);

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to realize that web pages are served over HTTP not raw TCP.  If you really want to use a Socket you're going to have to implement an HTTP GET request yourself.  I'll leave it up to you to figure that out if you so desire.

Alternatively you could use Java's built in URLconnection.  Please note the code below is far from production ready, but this should give you a general idea of how to use the Java URL connection.

```
public class WebPageSaver {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:/temp/test.html");

        URL url = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        copy(is, out);
        is.close();
        out.close();
    }

    private static void copy(InputStream from, OutputStream to) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while (true) {
            int numBytes = from.read(buffer);
            if (numBytes == -1) {
                break;
            }
            to.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it solved my problem with the help of Socket only,

Comment: @Raju Komaturi: why do you insist on using sockets? Using URL is the correct way.