# Taking text from a response web page using Java

Tags: java, browser, html

I am sending commands to a server using http, and I currently need to parse a response that the server sends back (I am sending the command via the command line, and the servers response appears in my browser).

There are a lot of resources such as this: [Saving a web page to a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079574/saving-a-web-page-to-a-file-in-java), that clearly illustrate how to scrape a page such as cnn.com.  However, since this is a response page that is only generated when the camera receives a specific command, my attempts to use the method described by Mike Deck (in the link above) have met with failure.  (Specifically, when my program requests the page again the server returns a 401 error.)

The response from the server opens a new tab in my browser.  Essentially, I need to know how to save the current web page using java, since reading in a file is probably the most simple way to approach this.  Do any of you know how to do this?

TL;DR How do you save the current webpage to a webpage.html or webpage.txt file using java?

**EDIT:** I used Base64 from the Apache commons codec, which solved my 401 authentication issue.  However, I am still getting a 400 error when I attempt to connect my InputStream (see below).  Does this mean a connection isn't being established in the first place?

```
    URL url = new URL ("http://"+ipAddress+"/axis-cgi/record/record.cgi?diskid=SD_DISK");
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("root:pass".getBytes());
    String encoding = new String (encodedBytes);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoInput (true);
    connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

    connection.connect();

    InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in   = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
    String line;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** Changing the request to a GET resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you try selenium?

Comment: I haven't.  It seems to me that it is more for testing, whereas I am attempting to simply save a page.  What is selenium used for?

Comment: Yes, it is the defacto standard tool for browser testing. It can do as if human is driving it. You could also try curl or http-client from apache.

Comment: I'm attempting to use http-client from apache (was recommended several places).  That solved my 401 error, but now I cannot seem to get the connection to speak with the foreign ipaddress.  (see my edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while scrutinizing my code above, I decided to change

```
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

to

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

This solved my problem.  In hindsight, I think the server was not recognizing the HTTP because it is not set up to handle the various trappings that come along with post.